# How to include third party libraries like jquery and bootstrap-table in index.html using webpack?

Tags: html, node.js, webpack, webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin

I saw tutorials regarding webpack and i'm able to bundle everything in bundle.js and i'm able to import jquery in .js files.

In my application i'm using ajax,bootstrap-table, so i need jquery and bootstrap-table in index.html

Using webpack how can i pack and load these in html file using webpack?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This is my webpack.config.js

var webpack =require('webpack');

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './app.js',
    output: {
        filename: './bundle.js'
    },
    node: {
      fs: 'empty',
      net: 'empty',
      tls: 'empty'
    },
    plugins:[
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({

        $:'jquery',
        jQuery:'jquery'
    })
    ]
};
```

If i want jquery in js file, in my nodejs file i'm adding `require('jquery')` but i want to load those in html?I didn't find much materials regarding this. If anyone knows please help!!!Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing bootstrap inside app.js too?

Based on the current setup, the bundle is generated in the directory in which you have your webpack config file.
if you already have your html template[index.html], then you should include the relative path of the bundled js file in the index.html

i.e. `<script src="./bundle.js"></script>`

else if you want the bundled file to be included dynamically in your index.html template, you should have a look at [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)

Comment: I want bootstrap only in the index.html.Bootstrap is available in bundle.js.So if i include bundle.js it should work right..It is not taking bootstrap-table and jquery..So my doubt is should i add anything similar to require('jquery') in html,so that it will be available in html?@Danny

Comment: jquery and tether need to be loaded before bootstrap.
in your webpack config, you could have your entry like `entry: ['./app.js', 'bootstrap']`;
in `app.js` you'd have 
`import JQuery from 'jquery'; import Tether from 'tether';`